# Syntax error in UPDATE query - VB Script

Tags: qtp, adodb

I'm trying to update the excel data while running QTP scripts, and for this I have the following snippet. But doesn't work and throws some error like 'Syntax error in UPDATE query'.

```
    strNonQuery = "Update [" & strDataSheet & "$] Set " & strFName & " = '" & strData & "'" &_
                                                            " where TS_ID = '" & m_strTestCase &_
                                                            "' and Iteration = " & m_intIteration &_
                                                            " and SubIteration = " & m_intSubIteration & ""
```

Can someone check and help me in this please?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely certain about the use of `Update [SomeValue$]` syntax in the query, but it's possible that one of the variables you are using to build your query is not populated like you think.  After building your string, try displaying it in a message box so you can see exactly what is being executed.

```
strNonQuery = "..." ' Your code here
MsgBox strNonQuery
```

You may find that the `m_intInteration` or `m_intSubIteration` variables are not populated with integer values and are resulting in invalid data when you build your query.

If you continue to have issues, you may want to post your full, expanded query instead of the VBScript syntax you are using to build it.